# In a chat of MS Teams, how to start unindented paragraph after bullet points

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-teams

I have something like this:

> Some texts without bullet points.
>
> - Texts texts texts texts texts
>
>   - Texts texts texts texts texts
> - Texts texts texts

What I want to do is to start a new line without a bullet point like this:

> Some texts without bullet points.
>
> - Texts texts texts texts texts
>
>   - Texts texts texts texts texts
> - Texts texts texts
>
> A new line without bullet points.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to do this?

Comment: Try with `SHIFT-TAB`

Comment: In many Microsoft products, pressing Backspace a couple of times in an empty bullet line will get rid of the bullet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a bulleted line with no text on it.

You're in at the end of your bulleted list:
[image]

You press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
[image]

You press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again:
[image]

... and type your message:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid of sending a message mistakenly when I use Enter key. Is there any way to avoid it? For example, can we set a custom shortcut for sending a message?

Comment: @Ogiad I share that concern. Whenever I'm writing some more complicated message in Teams (and I count bulleted lists as "more complicated"), I'll [click the Format button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WohN.png) to open the more advanced text editor. In that mode, pressing Enter does not send the message, it starts a new line. You have to click the Send button to sent the message.

Comment: Thank you, good to know that!

Answer (score 0):

Other simple ways:

1. Start new bullet item by e.g. pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Either:

- click the bullet icon in the toolbar:

[image: Icon]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut that changes the focus in the editor and in this case removes the bullet

Comment: Thanks! That also works!